# byte array to wav file

Tags: java, wav

EDIT: Thanks everyone! The problem was we had to decrypt block by block and save the original file format.

I'm trying to encrypt a sound file by blocks of 16 bytes size. Then decrypt it back and output the decrypted file.
The problem it throws "Stream of unsupported format" exception to the decrypted file I'm trying to save.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {

    File decryptedFile = new File("dec.wav");
    File soundFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\FROG1\\peeper5sec.wav");
    String k = "KEY";
    byte[] key = k.getBytes();
    
    Object keyKey=frog_Algorithm.makeKey(key);

    AudioInputStream st = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    byte[][] fileInByte = split(st.readAllBytes(),16);
    
    if (fileInByte == null)
        fileInByte[0] = st.readAllBytes();

    byte enc[]=null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );

    
    for (int i = 0; i < fileInByte.length; i++) {
        byte tmp3[]=frog_Algorithm.blockEncrypt(fileInByte[i], 0, keyKey);
        outputStream.write(tmp3);
    }
    enc=outputStream.toByteArray();
    
    
            
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    
    //fos.AudioSystem.write(frog_Algorithm.blockDecrypt(enc, 0,keyKey));
     //fos.close();
    byte[] dec=frog_Algorithm.blockDecrypt(enc, 0,keyKey);
    for (int i = 0; i < dec.length; i++) {
        fos.write(dec[i]);
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(dec);
    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bais);
    
     AudioSystem.write(stream, getAudioFileFormat(stream), decryptedFile);
```

Help?

Comment: I can not see any problem except that you encrypt blocks in 16 bytes but decrypt it back full..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create separate methods: One to load audio, one to encrypt, one to decrypt, one to play the audio.
2. Create unit tests so you can verify encryption and decryption (the value after decrypt must be the same as before encryption)
3. You probably have working code to load and play audio already
4. Put all four method calls into your test application and see if it still can play a sound

This will not solve your problem but give you a structured and maintainable approach. Very likely your encryption does not match the decryption.

You may want to replace your crypto efforts with [Apache commons-crypto](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/userguide.html).
Look at their example for [encryption/decryption of byte array](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/CipherByteArrayExample.html). But since you want to stream the results, it may be even better to look at [encryption/decryption of byte stream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/StreamExample.html).